# How to populate "Request -> Request Body" tab of a Jmeter Sampler result (displayed in the View Results Tree listener)?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Inside a JSR223 Sampler, I am currently using setResponseData(String response) method to populate the "Response data -> Response Body" tab of a Jmeter Sampler result with some data.

Like this:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(msg.getText())
```

This populates this section displayed in the View Results Tree listener:

[image]

I would like to also populate the "Request -> Request Body" tab of a Jmeter Sampler result viewed in the View Results Tree listener with some data, but I can't find something like SampleResult.setRequestData or setRequestBody etc...

Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SampleResult.setSamplerData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSamplerData-java.lang.String-) function should do the trick for you

```
SampleResult.setSamplerData('your custom request body')
```

More information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223): [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)